# Bash Script disk partition using fdisk command

Tags: bash

I have done new partition creation and mount the disk with manual interaction one after another, i got worked for me. But instead of doing manually i am planning to write the bash script to do all the changes for us without manual interaction.

I found the below script from internet, but i am not understand how the default option will behave using below sed  command

```
# to create the partitions programatically (rather than manually)
# we're going to simulate the manual input to fdisk
# The sed script strips off all the comments so that we can 
# document what we're doing in-line with the actual commands
# Note that a blank line (commented as "defualt" will send a empty
# line terminated with a newline to take the fdisk default.
sed -e 's/\s*\([\+0-9a-zA-Z]*\).*/\1/' << EOF | fdisk ${TGTDEV}
  o # clear the in memory partition table
  n # new partition
  p # primary partition
  1 # partition number 1
    # default - start at beginning of disk 
  +100M # 100 MB boot parttion
  n # new partition
  p # primary partition
  2 # partion number 2
    # default, start immediately after preceding partition
    # default, extend partition to end of disk
  a # make a partition bootable
  1 # bootable partition is partition 1 -- /dev/sda1
  p # print the in-memory partition table
  w # write the partition table
  q # and we're done
EOF

sudo fdisk /dev/sdc
p
n
1
p
w
lsblk
sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdc1
```

But after entering option p,n,1, i wanna make default for the rest of activity then finally i need write using option w.

Can you please some one help me how to make it work

code for sfdisk

```
  echo ';' | sfdisk /dev/sdc
  mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc1
  mount /dev/sdc1 /opt/app/
  uid=`blkid | grep sdc1 | sed -n 's/.*UUID=\"\([^\"]*\)\".*/\1/p'`
  echo "UUID=$uid /opt/app ext4  defaults  0  2" >> /etc/fstab
```

After executing sfdisk command after rebooting by REHL7 system not coming up back normal mode.

Comment: you should consider an alternative to `fdisk` which allows for better scripting integration, like `sfdisk`

Comment: I tried with option sfdisk but it does not helped me, i updated sfdisk code in above

Comment: The code in the second part of your script, `sudo fdisk /dev/sdc`, then `p` `n` `1` on extra lines, won't ever work; you need to feed those things to fdisk's stdin; as it is the code waits until fdisk exits and then tries to run `p` as a separate program. That's part of what using a pipeline or a heredoc accomplishes.

Comment: Anyhow, it's not clear what "make default for the rest of activity" even means. If we don't know what you're asking, how can we possibly answer the question?

Comment: Ok let come to your approach using sfdisk command, when i execute above code its working fine for me after rebooting i am not able to login to my machine

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This platform is intended for software developers.

Comment: seriously who will run a script that tries to partitioning something? it doesn't seem you are very experienced in scripting, i hope you do not share your work unless it's peer-reviewed and confirmed as bullet-proof

Answer (score 1):

You can do this concept via regular fdisk this way:

```
fdisk /dev/sdb << EOF
p
n
1



p
w
EOF
```

You merely need to know how many default values are needed.
You can have more, without any major consequences (cosmetic ones will occur, however)

> n has a max of 4 options [number, first, last, remove_old_fstype]

so you'd add `( 4 - len(args) )` newlines, then proceed.

**PS** n doesn't need 1 as the default argument ( as 1 is a default argument ), but the method I described above should work